# Prove Result Using Euler's Summation Formula

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I have had difficulty with applying Euler's Summation Formula for the following problem:

> Using Euler's Summation Formula, prove that for $x\gt1$ and for some constant $C$ such that $|{C}|\lt 1$
> $$\sum_{n\leq x} \frac{1}{1+n^2} = \tan^{-1}(x)+C+\mathcal{0}(\frac{1}{1+x^2})$$

I am using Tom Apostol's Analytic Number Theory and have had trouble even starting in the right place with this problem.

I start with $$
\sum_{y < n \leq x}f(n) = \int_y^x f(t)dt + \int_y^x(t-[t])f'(t)dt + f(x)([x] - x) - f(y)([y] - y)
$$
I have tried, seemingly incorrectly, to show $$\int \tan^{-1}(x)dx = \frac{1}{1+x^2}+C$$ as a place to start. Can someone help with an approach to this or a hint?

Comment: If you look at the Euler-Maclaurin formula, you can see that you need $
\int_0^x {\frac{{dt}}{{1 + t^2 }}} $ since $f(n)=\frac{1}{1+n^2}$.

Comment: If $\tan u = x$ then $~\displaystyle \frac{d}{du} x = \frac{d}{du} \tan(u) = \frac{1}{\cos^2(u)} = (x^2 + 1).$  The last portion follows, since if two of the legs of a right triangle are $x$ and $1$, then the hypotenuse is $\sqrt{1 + x^2}.$

Comment: You need to swap the functions: It's not $$\int \tan^{-1}(x)dx = \frac{1}{1+x^2}+C$$ but $$\int \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx = \tan^{-1}(x)+C$$

Comment: Why do you write $+f(x)([x]−x)−f(y)([y]−y)$ rather than $-f(x)(x-[x])+f(y)(y-[y])$? By $[x]$ you mean $\lfloor x\rfloor$, right?